# How to add total orders into PayPal javascript button

Tags: javascript, paypal, sandbox

We have a paypal sandbox checkout button for the website and we have to insert our cart totals into the javascript for it to work.

```
payment: function (data, actions) {
    return actions.payment.create({
      transactions: [{
        amount: {
          total: '0.01',
          currency: 'USD'
        }
      }]
    });
  },
```

How can we retrieve the total amount from our DB and show it on the page?

Query for total:

```
insert the total amount from query for the total SELECT SUM(iQty * iUnitPrice) AS Total FROM OrdersItem WHERE (iOrderID = @Param1)
```

Thank you

Comment: Not sure I follow. From the way this question is worded it sounds like you're trying to call SQL from you front end (which you should not be doing). Could you clarify?

Comment: Basically, I have a SQL database where the total amount for the shopping cart is stored. I also have a Paypal popup that I need said total amount to show up in. The code above is the function I am using, but I'm not sure how to implement it. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I assume your PayPal popup meant to be speaking with a WebService (which in turn speaks to your database to add the payment). Is this correct?